# remote desktop gateway licensing mode for administrator only usage

Tags: remote-desktop-services

I have setup a remote desktop gateway but only intend to use it for administrative access to servers.  Correct me if I am wrong but as long as I am only using the RD Gateway for administrative purposes and limit it to two connections per server at a time I don't need licenses.

If that is true then, how do I get the gateway to not expire after the grace period?

Comment: No that is not correct.  And you need to contact Microsoft for licensing questions.  "Do I need an RDS CAL if I am not running a multiuser environment but use functionality in Remote Desktop
Services - for example, Remote Desktop Gateway?
Yes. An RDS CAL is required to use any functionality included in the Remote Desktop Services role in Windows Server. [...] if you are using RDS Gateway [...] to provide access to a Windows client [...]" http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/WindowsServerRDS_VLBrief.pdf

Comment: I have read the "Licensing Windows Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Services" brief.  Where my interpretation is coming from is that document, page 2 paragraph 2: "Note: No RDS CALs are required for up to two users to access instances of the server software for administration purposes."

Comment: You're confusing Remote Desktop for Administration with Remote Desktop Gateway.  You need licenses to use RD Gateway, 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is more or less correct. If you don't add the licenses, it will terminate other sessions when sessions past the first two are created. There's also a console session which has special rules.